# NFTs not being immediately recognized on Testnet

Tags: testnet, nft

Using the ghostnet when minting NFTs sometimes they are quickly reflected on the wallet. Sometimes it takes a long time.

Why is that? Can it be made quicker (or checked)? (it is hard for testing if you have to wait an undetermined amount of time to see if it went through).

Initial state:
[image]

After some time:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It mostly depends on the IPFS network propagation, which service do you use for pinning, what is the time lag between uploading the metadata and injecting the mint transaction, and if you warm up public IPFS gateways prior to minting.

General recommendations are the following:

- Use a common pinning service, if possible, let us know the peer id so we can have a direct connection to the node
- Warm up public gateway caches (just query your file e.g. using this list https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/) before minting a token